# Objective C NSData to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm learning to develop an iPad Application using cocoaAsyncSocket for my TCP connection.

When i print the NSData into the console, it prints the whole data in hex. When i convert to NSString and prints, it always prints the first byte only.

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
```

`NSString *msg =  [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

`NSLog(@"Server Reply data: %@", data);`

`NSLog(@"Server Reply: %@",msg);`
`}`

the print out from console was :
"Server Reply data: <4b000230 30303037 33323030 35342020>"
"Server Reply: K"

Am i converting it wrongly?

And is it possible to stop when the data reads a ETX(03) in hex for cocoaAsyncsocket? i seen that it is possible to read CRLF.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`4b000230 30303037 33323030 35342020`, parsed as UTF8 is the ASCII-compatible code 0x4b (or, 'K') and then a 0x00, which is interpreted as a terminating NULL. So NSString is acting entirely correctly.

Is it possible you're actually receiving UTF16 or some other encoding?

EDIT: if it's just that you're getting two bytes that aren't part of the string (based on the sample in the comments it looks like the length of the entire packet of data, including the two bytes containing the length?) then you can do something like:

```
NSData *originalData = <whatever came back from the web service>;
NSData *subData = [NSData
                   dataWithBytes:((char *)[originalData bytes]) + 2
                          length:[originalData length] - 2];
```

That'll cause the data to be copied. You can avoid that if you really want but the semantics get a little more confusing and it's not going to make a measurable difference with a web service in the background.

Hand decoding from the third byte onwards it looks like the stream is:

```
02  [start of text control code; NSString will render this as ¿]
30  0
30  0
30  0
30  0
37  7
33  3
32  2
30  0
30  0
35  5
34  4
20  [space]
20  [space]
```

Does that look like the sort of thing you're expecting to find? Given that neither 0x02 or 0x03 will cause the NSString to terminate, if you're confident about the length then I think the easiest thing to do is to remove them after the NSString is created (via `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` or NSMutableString's `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`, saving you from any errors where 0x02 or 0x03 crop up in the byte stream as part of a multi-byte character.

Comment: I don't think its other encoding that i'm receiving. is it possible that the conversion terminates at NULL?

Comment: The conversion does terminate at NULL, but that's because NULL terminates C strings. Unicode just seems to define it as a control character. If you're getting an HTTP response, is there an encoding in the header? In any case do you know what string you're expecting to receive?

Comment: the msg start with STX (02) and ends with ETX(03).

When cocoaasyncsocket reads data, it has a delimiter, when i set the delimiter to "", it reads and converts the entire data, when i set it to ETX ("03"), it only converts the first character.

Comment: the reply was 39000230 30303035 35303030 30302020 20202030 33333331 20203031 31303220 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20292020 03. but the reply should be WITHOUT the 3900. is it possible to do a SUBDATA? like find the 02 (STX) and start, and end at 03 (ETX)?

Comment: You can use NSData's dataWithBytes:length: and C's standard pointer stuff to create a sub data. I'm on an iPad now, but I'll add a quick example in case it's helpful when I get to a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSString *aString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: cocoaasyncsocket has this delimiter to end the msg in right? default is CRLF `return [NSData dataWithBytes:"\x0D\0A" length:2];`

used your method to decode, it works only for `return [NSData dataWithBytes:"" length:1];`


as the repy ends with ETX, i changed it to `return [NSData dataWithBytes:"\x03\" length:1];`

it only returns the first String character when i used your method to change data to string..